# Polly policy to throw an exception when Execute() is called

Tags: c#, polly

I am using a slightly dated version of Polly - [5.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly/5.9.0) in one of my projects.

For a test case, I am trying to create a policy that will always throw an exception when `Execute()` is called on it. This policy will be injected into the actual code at test time and the expectation is for it to fail.

I could do something like:

```
Policy somePolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().Retry();
somePolicy.Execute((cToken) => { throw new Exception(); }, new Context("A context"), cancellationToken);
```

However, I do not have access of or control over the first parameter of `Execute()`, i.e., the `(cToken) => { throw new Exception(); }` part.

I have also tried a workaround using `HandleResult()` as follows:

```
Policy<bool> somePolicy = Policy.HandleResult<bool>((o) => { throw new Exception(); }).Retry();
```

This works, however, the `Policy<bool>` makes it cumbersome to integrate with the rest of the code which uses just `Policy`.

The policy itself does not matter, as long as it throws an exception on any invocation of `Execute()`.
Is there a clean way of achieving this?

PS: Upgrading Polly isn't an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

## 1 Use [Simmy](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Simmy)

[Simmy](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Simmy) is a project providing Polly policies for injecting faults.

For instance, you can define:

```
var faultPolicy = MonkeyPolicy.InjectFault(new FooException());
```

(and many other more powerful variants).

However, this is only compatible with Polly v7+.

## 2 Use policy interfaces and mock policies

Polly policies all [fulfil execution interfaces](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-interfaces).  Depending on the policy:

- `ISyncPolicy`
- `ISyncPolicy<TResult>`
- `IAsyncPolicy`
- `IAsyncPolicy<TResult>`

These interfaces define the `.Execute/Async()` overloads available on the policy.

With these, you can use standard dependency-injection and mocking techniques to construct a test:

- In your production code, declare and consume policies by the execution interface type.
- Make sure the `ISyncPolicy` or similar (or a `PolicyRegistry`) is injected into the system-under-test, not created within it, so that tests can substitute a mock.
- In the unit-test, instead pass in a `Mock<ISyncPolicy>`.  You can then use any mocking tool like Moq to mock the `.Execute()` call through the policy to throw an exception.

For example:

```
ISyncPolicy mockPolicy = new Mock<ISyncPolicy>();
mockPolicy.Setup(p => p.Execute(It.IsAny<Func<Bar>>())
    .Throws(new FooException());
```

This and more is covered in more detail on the [Polly wiki on unit-testing](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Unit-testing-with-Polly---with-examples#3-i-want-to-unit-test-how-my-code-reacts-to-results-or-faults-returned-by-the-execution-through-polly), with code examples.